# Who is responsible for putting the null terminator when handling TB_GETBUTTONTEXT?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, memory-management

The documentation for [TB_GETBUTTONTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787325(v=VS.85).aspx) says that the handler has to return the number of characters and optionally (if `lParam` is not null) copy the string into the supplied buffer.

The caveat is that the length doesn't include the terminating character. I see the following problem. Say the handler stores the string precomputed (so its length doesn't change). First the caller sends the message with `lParam` set to null - to find the number of characters - and the handler returns the number of characters without the terminating null. Then the caller allocates memory and sends the message again - this time passing  the buffer address as `lParam`.

Should the handler copy the terminating null? I mean if the first time the handler returned `N` and the caller allocated space for `N` characters and the handler appends a terminating null then buffer overrun occurs. But if the caller really expected the string to be null terminated and allocated space for `N+1` characters and the handler doesn't append the null terminator the handler will have a string that is not null-terminated and again buffer overrun can occur (if the caller isn't careful enough).

So what should the handler do? Should it copy the null terminator or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFC uses the sane approach in its CMFCToolBar::OnGetButtonText() implementation, it assumes the caller knows it should allocate N+1 and uses lstrcpy() to copy the text.